# Is it normal for my Galaxy S5 to always bring up a prompt to "check battery cover" when powering up/rebooting?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5

I recently got a Galaxy S5 and I'm new to the android platform so apologies in advance if this is an obvious question.

I've noticed that my phone brings up a prompt during startup (after a full poweroff) stating to check my battery cover.  It looks like this:

[image]

Does this mean that the phone senses the cover being loose?  Or is this just a generic message that comes up every time I boot?

Comment: I have the same doubt.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Generic message after reboot. It will show everytime and I think you cannot turn it off.

Comment: This does not seem likely.  Many phones have contacts for detecting the back cover, probably one is bent or something.

Comment: There is something under cover that looks like this detector, but still it shows up after every reboot. This is probably just a reminder so you will not be sorry later